# Props not being recognized

Tags: reactjs

below is the declared variable that I got from backend.

```
function DateTimeFilterComponent(props) {
  const { chartPeriod } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  let timeStampData = {};
  let dateFrom = '';
  let dateTo = '';

  if (!isEmpty(chartPeriod) && chartPeriod) {
    timeStampData = Object.values(chartPeriod).map(payload => payload);
    const [dateOne, dateTwo] = timeStampData[1].timeStamps;
    dateFrom = dateOne;
    dateTo = dateTwo;
  }

  return (
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate>
      <Grid container alignments="flex-end">
        <Grid item>
          <DateTimeComponent controlName="dateFrom" defaultValue={dateFrom} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <DateTimeComponent controlName="dateTo" defaultValue={dateTo} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
}
```

dateFrom and dateTo return type is string i.e "2021-07-12T00:00", and I assigned to my component like the following:

```
<DateTimeComponent controlName="dateFrom" defaultValue={dateFrom} />
<DateTimeComponent controlName="dateTo" defaultValue={dateTo} />
```

However, in my TextField component the dateFrom and dateTo are not being recognized when I'm assigning it on my useState.

```
function DateTimeComponent(props) {
  const { controlName, defaultValue } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [getDate, setDate] = React.useState(defaultValue);

  const handleChangeDate = e => {
    setDate(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      id={controlName}
      type="datetime-local"
      value={getDate}
      className={classes.textField}
      size="small"
      onChange={handleChangeDate}
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
      inputProps={{ className: classes.inputSize }}
    />
  );
}
```

But when I declare the value like this, the useState recognized the string value and being set in the textfield correctly.

```
    <DateTimeComponent controlName="dateFrom" defaultValue="2021-07-12T00:00" />
    <DateTimeComponent controlName="dateTo" defaultValue="2021-07-12T00:00" />
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong and makes the weird behavior.

Thank you

Comment: console.log your dateFrom and dateTo first. do they have values?

Comment: The example is incomplete. What is `chartPeriod`? That's where you get the initial data from. Make sure you don't render the component using `useState` before you have the initial default date. Passing a default value to useState only works on the initial render in the component lifecycle.

Comment: @Apostolos - both dates return "2021-07-12T00:00" and "2021-07-12T08:00"

Comment: @HåkenLid - chartPeriod returns an array of two time stamps which is the date I provided.

Comment: If that's the case, then your first example that you say is not working should have given the same output as your second example, where you use hardcoded literal timestamps.

Comment: I think you need to add a `useEffect` on `defaultValue`.

Comment: please add full code if possible. most probably you need useEffect but this means that you call your component in a way that for an instance defaultValue is undefined.

Comment: @HåkenLid - That's make it weirder, when I use the hardcoded literal, its working fine. The getDate correctly assigned the hardcoded literal and applied it in the textfield value.

Comment: @Apostolos - I edited the post and posted the full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK this means that the first time your component is rendered, for an instance `defaultValue` is empty (till you get the actual value from backend).

So in order to fix this, you need either to add this

```
{dateFrom && <DateTimeComponent controlName="dateFrom" defaultValue={dateFrom} />}

{dateTo && <DateTimeComponent controlName="dateTo" defaultValue={dateTo} />}
```

or to add `useEffect` in your `DateTimeComponent` component like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setDate(defaultValue)
  }, [ defaultValue ])
```

Comment: Thank you very much about this Apostolos, the useEffect do the trick.

Comment: @FunkySloth dont forget to accept answer. thank you!